# Is the BPB necessary for a bootloader to load correctly in Bochs?

Tags: assembly, bootloader, bochs

I am writing a bootloader for a FAT12 floppy disk and creating an IMG image using [BFI](http://www.nu2.nu/bfi/). If I remove the [BPB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_parameter_block) code from my bootloader Assembly, I receive the following error in [Bochs](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bochs):

`MOV_EwSw: using of nonexisting segment register 7`

This bootloader simply prints a string.

Is the BPB code necessary in Bochs? And why?

**The code**

```
bits    16

org     0x7c00

start:          jmp loader

bpbOEM          db "My OS   "

bpbBytesPerSector:      DW 512
bpbSectorsPerCluster:   DB 1
bpbReservedSectors:     DW 1
bpbNumberOfFATs:        DB 2
bpbRootEntries:         DW 224
bpbTotalSectors:        DW 2880
bpbMedia:               DB 0xF0
bpbSectorsPerFAT:       DW 9
bpbSectorsPerTrack:     DW 18
bpbHeadsPerCylinder:    DW 2
bpbHiddenSectors:       DD 0
bpbTotalSectorsBig:     DD 0
bsDriveNumber:          DB 0
bsUnused:               DB 0
bsExtBootSignature:     DB 0x29
bsSerialNumber:         DD 0xa0a1a2a3
bsVolumeLabel:          DB "MOS FLOPPY "
bsFileSystem:           DB "FAT12   "

msg db 0xD, 0xA, "Welcome to My Operating System!", 0

Print:
            lodsb
            or          al, al
            jz          PrintDone
            mov         ah, 0eh
            int         10h
            jmp         Print
PrintDone:
            ret

loader:

    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    mov si, msg
    call Print

    xor ax, ax
    int 0x12

    cli
    hlt

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0

dw 0xAA55
```

Comment: No, it's not required. You forgot to show your code ;)

Comment: Works fine here even if I remove everything from `bpbOEM` to `bsFileSystem` inclusive (bochs 2.4.6).